# Connect to a database of an X system to get information for my journey

Tags: automationstudio, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud

I have a question. If I wanted to connect to a database of an X system to get information for my journey. Is it necessary to create a webservices or is it only configuration through automation studio or contact builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will always recommend you to synchronise this data to Marketing Cloud on an ongoing basis - using either SFTP/Automation Studio (using File Import Activity) or through SOAP/REST API.

The first option is best suited for high volume batch transfers, while API is better for pushing fewer rows of data in real time.

Since you need this specifically for journey builder, you could opt for a custom activity. However this requires substantial custom development. Also - it introduces a dependency on both the infrastructure hosting this custom activity, as well as the data source being polled.

Why data should reside inside Marketing Cloud, is therefore both a question of performance, as well as robustness. Relying on fetching data from an external source WHEN you need it, poses a real risk of that data source either not being available or introducing significant latency.

For details on integration capabilities and data modelling in Marketing Cloud, I would suggest you to take a look at this Trail: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/develop-for-marketing-cloud

Comment: Ok, so does it mean that all the information must be in cloud marketing? Because if I have for example an SQL base with 1 million clients, I have to upload that million to cloud marketing, place it in a data extension and just apply my filters to start a journey. Is that so?

Comment: That’s entirely correct

Comment: @AlonsoDelaFuente - do remember to upvote/accept my answer, if it has been helpful

Comment: ok. Im so sorry